# How to disable device back button in nested views in Ionic Framework? v1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, back-button, phonegap

How to disable device back button in nested views in Ionic Framework v1?

I have already tried this

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
    if ($ionicHistory.currentView().stateName == 'main.homeState' ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }, 100);
```

But the problem is it only works on root level views, i.e app gets closed if it's the root view in my case the homeState but on any other nested views the back button does not get disabled.

Actually I have 3 nested views. state1 is the root view state2 is the child view of state1 and state3 is the child view of state2. Now if use app back button or device back button to go back from state 3 everything works perfect. But if I move back from state3 to state2 using app's back button and then press the device back button instead of going to the root view state 1. It navigates to state 3 again.

Answer (score 0):

use this code into  $ionicPlatform.ready, it will disable android back button and click.

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
   return false;
});
```